# Hide dropdownlist from backend does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dropdown

I have a really strange problem that I can't understand.

I use ASP.NET version .NET 4.0

In my case I need to hide `DropDownList` `if(condition is true)`.
But none of the hide options work.

Here is the code part(this actions calls from another dropdown by OnSelectedIndexChanged):

```
if (id_int == 3)
{
    DropDown_typeofcar.Attributes["style"] = "display: none;";
    DropDown_typeofcar.Visible = false;
    DropDown_typeofcar.Enabled = false;
}
```

and design:

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDown_typeofcar" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CarType" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataValueField="CarType" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CarType_Changed2" Width="200px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Please help me to figure out what may be the problem. If you need additional information, let me know.

Comment: Code works if you put it in PageLoad. But in my case I call his action from the another dropdown. When a specific value was selected, than hide this dropdown. Maybe there is a problem with postback?

Comment: If you debug step by step your code you will find that probably you do not call that line of code. You have some bug - the code is work only with the `.visible=false`

Comment: I tried to debug and it gos from that part of code

Comment: So as you see, somewhere else is your bug...